# why do some conda channels work but not others

Tags: anaconda, conda, nvidia

I'm unable to download packages from certain conda channels,but other channels work just fine.

To demonstrate, I made a new conda environment

`conda create --name fastai2 python=3.7`

Which runs just fine.

`conda activate fastai2`

Then, I want to install, NVIDIA rapids,

`conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge  -c defaults rapids=0.13 python=3.7`

Which then proceeds to try to install lot of packages. However anything from the nvidia or rapidsai channels fail.

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
nvstrings-0.13.0     | 129 KB    |                                                                               |   0%
dask-xgboost-0.2.0.d | 14 KB     |                                                                               |   0%
pygments-2.6.1       | 683 KB    | ############################################################################# | 100%
libnvstrings-0.13.0  | 29.6 MB   |                                                                               |   0%
libnetcdf-4.7.4      | 1.3 MB    | ############################################################################# | 100%

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai/linux-64/nvstrings-0.13.0-py37_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

My condarc looks like this.

```
ssl_verify: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/XXXXX_https_intercept.crt    
allow_conda_downgrades: true    
channels:    
- conda-forge    
- defaults 

proxy_servers:
    http: http://XXXXXXX
    https: https://XXXXXXX
```

I can use wget or curl to down the packages, so no blocked websites via company firewall.

I also have problems with other channels. Like when I try to install fastai.
`conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai`

I've tried all sorts of stuff for the last 2 days. Like these issues which seem similar. 
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007

Any help would be appreciated.

Anthony

Comment: When trying to install pytorch, you get the same error?

Comment: Is it consistent in which packages/channels always fail to work correctly? It looks to me like your internet connection might be unstable

Comment: I was able to get it to work by appending my company certificate to certifi "cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/XXXX_https_intercept.crt >>  /home/XXX/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem"

    
I'm not saying this is a solution, since I don't really understand why it worked.Plus this might make future problems when trying to update certifi.